# how does one prove the associative rule for addition of positive real numbers in elementary terms

Tags: number-theory

I want to know how do I prove the associative rule for addition in elementary terms. I searched about the proof on Google but I was not able to figure head or tail about it. So how does one prove the associative rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case we have axiomatized:

1. $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\sum_{i^1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}$ for a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ (addition is commutative)
2. $x+y+z=(x+y)+z$ (you evaluate addition from left to right - reading direction)

Then we can prove:
$$
(x+y)+z=x+y+z=y+z+x=(y+z)+x=x+(y+z)
$$
But it has to be based on axioms, after all.

Comment: Are these axioms you have mentioned proved?

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay: No! Axioms are never proven, only agreed upon. For instance: How can you prove to me, that counting the number of people in a room is invariant to the order in which you count them? It seems to always be the case, which we all agree, but why?

Comment: So similarly we can agree on some axioms such that they prove the Riemann hypothesis. But that is not possible so why here?@String

Answer (score 2):

Associativity can't be "proven", only demonstrated. It is an assumption, one of the requirements for addition to be a group operation.

Comment: But why can't itbe proven?

Comment: Or is there any way to show that it can't be proven

Comment: Because it doesn't follow from anything. It is part of the *definition* of addition. there are plenty of other operations on real numbers that are *not* associative (subtraction and addition are two familiar ones). See this link (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html).

Comment: You could "prove" it by defining the sum of two nonnegative integers as the size of the set that is the union of two disjoint sets of the specified sizes--but then that depends on the assumption that the union operation on sets is associative. You would then ask how to "prove" that. So in that case you are just shifting the problem to another realm, and in the end you really do have to assume something is associative. This just hides it elsewhere, not really getting around anything. Plus, you would have to extend this to the reals somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In Rudin's book, Principles of Mathematics, the real numbers are constructed using Dedekind cuts with a '$\mathbb Q$' build. He defines a binary operation $=$ on the set of cuts, and does indeed prove that this operation is associative (it follows immediately from the fact that addition is associative on the rational numbers).

But, for the sake of argument, suppose you have constructed the real numbers by another means and that you have defined a commutative binary operation $+$ that is associative on a 'dense' subset $Q$. Let $x, y, z \in \mathbb R$ and suppose you can find $a,b,c,e,f,g \in Q$ such that

$\tag 1 a + (b + c) \lt x + (y+z) \lt (a + e) + [(c + e) + (f + g)]$

But then

$\tag 2 (a + b) + c \lt x + (y+z) \lt [(a + b) + c] + e + f + g$

If you can take $e,f,g$ to be arbitrarily small numbers, then can 'squeeze down' so that  you must conclude that

$\tag 3  x + (y+z) = (x+y) +z$